# how to delete duplicates of a merge sorted array

Tags: c++, merge

I have the following code, which merge sort an unsorted array in an ascending order.

Now I would like to delete the repeated duplicate numbers

for example if I have : 1  2  3  4  4  5  6  7
output should be:       1  2  3  4  5  6  7

the code works and gives the right output for the example above. however if the array is : 1  2  3  4  6  6  6  7

the i will go out of bound and there will be an error.

how to fix it ?

My code is below. Focus on the deletion part only, as the merge sort is working fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void mergeSort(int *a, int low, int high);
void merge(int *a, int low, int high, int mid);
int main()
{
    int myArray[] = {2,3,1,6,7,8,3,9};
    int sortedArray[7];
    int low= 0;
    int high = 7;

    mergeSort(myArray, low, high);


    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        cout << myArray[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;

    ////////////////delete duplicate///////////////////

    int j=0;
    for(int i =0; i <8; i++)
    {
    if(myArray[i] == myArray[i+1]) //if there is a duplicate at next spot
        {
            sortedArray[j] = myArray[i];
            i++;   //skip the i index from the duplicate array
            j++;   // move the sorted array index forward
        }
        else
        {
            sortedArray[j] = myArray[i];   
            j++;   //move the sorted array index forward
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        cout << sortedArray[i] << " ";

}

void mergeSort(int *a, int low, int high)
{
    int mid;
    if(low < high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        mergeSort(a, low, mid);
        mergeSort(a, mid+1, high);
        merge(a,low,high,mid);
    }

    return;
}

void merge(int *a, int low, int high, int mid) 
{
    int i, j, k;
    i= low;
    j= mid +1;
    k= low;
    int c[8];

    while(i <= mid && j <= high)
    {
        if(a[i] < a[j])
        {
            c[k] = a[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            c[k] = a[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }

    while(i <= mid)
    {
        c[k] = a[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }

    while(j <= mid)
    {

        c[k] = a[j];

        k++;

        j++;

    }

     for (i = low; i < k; i++)

    {

        a[i] = c[i];

    }



    }
```

Comment: This is probably an assignment where you can't use vectors, but I really think it would be faster to solve it using vectors (which good debuggers will bounds check) and then convert the code back to arrays.

Comment: If you have an editor which can automatically reindent your code, use that feature and you will see your error quite clearly.

Comment: @NeilKirk I agree. I will write the same program in vector when I am done with this. Arrays create so many problems

Comment: Also, you read `myArray` out of bounds when `i ` equals `7`.

Comment: right @JoachimPileborg . how to delete sorted  duplicates then ?

Comment: C++ have many nice [algorithm function in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). So you can first [sort it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) then [remove consecutive duplicates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Comment: It is already sorted. I merge sorted it as seen in the code above... @JoachimPileborg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot { and } to group two statements after else.

there's bug, if the array is 1 4 4 4 5 your code will go wrong guy.

a better solution:

```
i = 0; j = 0;
while (i<length)
{
    sortedArr[j] = myArr[i];
    j++;
    k = i+1;
    while (k < length && myArr[i]=myArr[k]) k++;
    i = k;
}
```

Comment: what does that mean please ellaborate

Comment: else
{
sortedArr[j] = myArr[i];
j++ }

Comment: How do you fix the bug ? @Linh

Comment: but there's still bug, you'd better use 2 while statements instead of one for and one if

Comment: putting k inside while loo[ is bringing an error: expression has to be modifiable value

Comment: just declare both i, j and k before your while statemant, example, add a block like this { int i=0; int j=0; int k; while..... } Both i, j, k will be alive inside this block only, they will be destroyed before '}'

Comment: excuse me for my bad writing ^^

Comment: if you need j for later uses as get the length of sortedArr, you can declare it outside